# Get a specific value from a Datatable c#

Tags: c#, datatable, datatables

I'm starting to use **Datatable** with C# and I have a big one ready. But the problem comes when I try to find an ID and get his value. For example:

Get the red value where the column is called "Cantidad" and the Nivel 2 is 15 (15 = 443MC). How can I do it without going through the entire Datatable with for, while ... only knowing "Nivel 2" that and then store that value in a variable?

[image]

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: please refer to [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly. Thank you

Comment: @PabloRecalde Thank you, edited with an example of the datatable. The red value is what I want to get.

Comment: Are you just looking for the `.Select()` method?:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.select?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: List<DataRow> results =  dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<int>("Quantity").ToList();  You can also to get a new table replace ToList() with CopyToTable()

Comment: @David could be :) with that .Select() how can I make a query to get the red value? like this: dataTable.Select("what would be here¿?")

Comment: Use CopyToTable()

Comment: @GetData: Look at the examples on that linked page.  You are looking for a row where a `SomeColumn = '443MC'`, no?

Comment: @David sorry, to be concrete I am looking for the red value, only knowing that "Nivel 2 = 443MC" so I want to get the column "Cantidad" where Nivel 2 is 443MC

Comment: @GetData: So... `.Select("[Nivel 2] = '443MC'")`?

Comment: @David but with .Select("[Nivel 2] = '443MC'") I would get the complete row, but to get the value of the column "Cantidad" of that row?

Comment: @David, you right, but I have to look for in english and thats the problem. But thank you for your help David!

Answer (score 2):

Can something like this could be helpful?

```
DataRow[] dataRowList = dataTable.Select("[Nivel 2] = '443MC'");

foreach(DataRow dataRow in dataRowList)
{
    string cantidadValue = dataRow["Cantidad"].ToString();
}
```